# Detecting when an iframe is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, iframe

I am using the following code in order to check if an iframe has been clicked:

```
<script>
            focus();
            var listener = addEventListener('blur', function() {
                if(document.activeElement = document.getElementById('rhfrm_46861_71019_0')) {
                    $.ajax({ url: 'execute.php',
                     data: {action: 'test'},
                     type: 'post'
                    });
                }
                removeEventListener(listener);
            });
            </script>
```

However when I'm switching tabs, or I'm minimizing the window, the code still gets executed. How can I make it so that the ajax function is being called only when the user clicks the iframe?

Comment: You used `=` instead of `==`

Comment: Nevermind. Now the code doesn't get called at all! What can I do?

Comment: Why don't you just add an event listener to the iframe for the `click` event?

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer to your question, "Detecting when an iframe is clicked"  you can try something like this:

```
$('iframe').on('click', function(e) { 
      console.log('iframe clicked');
});
```

Remember that it won't work if the iframe is from a different domain than the host page.

Comment: It's from a different domain (I'm using iframes from RevenueHits ads)

Comment: Well then that domain have to support C.O.R.S or JSONP etc. But there are always workarounds and hacks ;p just google it